# continuity and limits of $f(x,y)= \begin{cases} \frac{y\ln(x+1)}{y^2+(\ln(x+1))^2} &\text{if $y \neq 0$ }\\0&\text{if $ y=0$}\end{cases}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity, logarithms, solution-verification

Given the set $D:=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: x > -1\}$ and the function $f: D\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ through
$f(x,y)=  \begin{cases} \frac{y\ln(x+1)}{y^2+(\ln(x+1))^2} &\text{if $y \neq 0$ }\\0&\text{if $ y=0$}\end{cases}$

(i) Show that $\lim_{y\to 0} f (1,y) =0$ and $\lim_{x\to 1} f (x,0) =0$

(ii) Show that $\lim_{n\to \infty}(\frac{1}{n}, \ln (\frac{1}{n}+1))=(0,0)$

(iii) Show that $f$ is not continuous in $(0,0)$

To (i)

$\lim_{x\to 1} f (x,0) =0$ follows by definition, since $y=0$.

$\lim_{y\to 0} f (1,y) = \frac{0}{(\ln(2))^2}=0$

To (ii)

$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n}=0$

$\lim_{n\to \infty} \ln (\frac{1}{n}+1) = 0$

To (iii)

It is $X_m\to X_0\iff F(X_m)\to F(X_0)$

$X_m:=(\frac{1}{n}, \ln (\frac{1}{n}+1))$ converges $(o,o)$ But $f((X_m) = \frac{1}{2} \neq F(0,0)=0 \Rightarrow f$ is not continuous in $(0,0)$

Comment: In your answer to (i) $\lim \limits_{y\to 0} f (1,y)$ is nowhere to be found. In (ii) you're not computing the required limit, not sure what you're doing. I'm not sure how your attempt at (iii) relates to the question either.

Comment: In (ii) did you mean $\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}\left[f\left(\frac{1}{n}, \log \left(\frac{1}{n}+1\right)\right)\right]=(0,0)$?

Comment: Yes, where is my mistake? I can't see it..

Comment: You forgot the $f$ in the question...

Comment: Sorry, i missunderstood you. I've written the task down correctly, i thought you were resonding to my solution. But $f$ maps in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: OK. But in your attempt at (ii) you're computing $\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}\left[f\left(\frac{1}{n}, \log \left(\frac{1}{n}+1\right)\right)\right]$ instead of $\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{1}{n}, \log \left(\frac{1}{n}+1\right)\right)$. Do you realise this?

Comment: So i've missunderstood the task wrong and it has nothing to do with function $f$ at all? (But i guess with (iii))...

Comment: Yes, (ii) is completely independent of $f$ (but (ii) is useful for (iii)). Do you now understand what you need to do to solve (ii)?

Comment: I think i just have to consider $\frac{1}{n}$ and $\ln(\frac{1}{n}+1)$ seperatly and show that each of them converges to $0$

Comment: Exactly. You should have a result in your notes somewhere saying that it's enough to consider the sequences separately. So you got (ii) down?

Comment: Yes, i think so. Thanks man

Comment: No problem. To answer (iii), look through your notes for a result that says something like "$F$ is continuous at $X_0$ if, and only if, for all sequences $(X_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$  one has $X_m\to X_0\iff F(X_m)\to F(X_0)$" (this might even be the definition of continuity). Use this together with (ii) to answer (iii).

Comment: I hope that it's now correct

Comment: I added the tag (solution-verifcation) because it's what this question became. It's essentially correct, but there are a few details that should be improved. In my previous comment I left out some hypothesis like all $X_m$ must be in the domain of $F$ so you should check that this happens. Also you didn't specify what $X_0$ is and you're using $F$ and $f$ interchangeably. Be consistent with your notations. Finally you typed $X_m:=\left(\frac{1}{n}, \ln \left(\frac{1}{n}+1\right)\right)$, but you're using two different variables, stick to only one. Otherwise it's fine.

Comment: If no one answers the question, say, by tomorrow. It would be good if you answered the question yourself so it doesn't come up as unanswered.